# Uninstall and install MPI

Tags: parallels, mpi

As far as I know, I cannot reinstall `MPI` from the terminal.

For this reason, I want to know how I can repair `MPI` (uninstall and install `MPI`) using a security method in terminal?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

`$ apt-cache search MPI | grep -w MPI` will list (on MY system) **47** `MPI` related packages.

`$ apt-cache search MPI | grep -w MPI| awk '{print $1}' | xargs dpkg -l 2>/dev/null` will show you which ones you have installed on your system.

You can achieve "(uninstall and install mpi)" by feeding the package names to `sudo apt install --reinstall`.

However, in the Ubuntu world, "uninstall and reinstall" never fixes the problem. Never.

If you've messed up the configuration of a package, you can use `dpkg-reconfigure`  to reconfigure an already installed package. Read `man dpkg-reconfigure`.

If it's some other problem, read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if I directly reinstall MPI, it should be dangerous, if I uninstall MPI, then install MPI, Must I reinstall MPI related apps?